# How to label boolean return value of Promise<boolean>?

Tags: typescript

I am writing a function that returns a promise that resolves to `true` if it succeeded or false if it failed.

I would like to use the auto-documentation features of TypeScript to let users of this function know what that boolean represents.

Is there a way to label that boolean as `success`?

Bellow is the interface that defines that function.

```js
interface ContextProps {
  logout?: () => Promise<boolean>
}
```

Comment: No; the caller can assign it to whatever name it likes, it only knows the *type* of the value. The ways to maintain that information are: name the function (`doThingAndReturnSuccess`); or don't use primitive types (at minimum you can define your own named equivalent `type Success = true | false;` - see e.g. https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#3-wrap-all-primitives-and-strings).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Using `type`, I still see `(property) ContextProps.logout?: () => Promise<boolean>` when I mouse over `context.logout()` in Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to see `type Success = true | false;`?

Comment: Looks like no, you'd have to use a proper encapsulation like `interface Success { succeeded: boolean }`.